# Multiple checkbox filter: how to get both and additive and subtractive effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make checkboxes that hide and show div items based on what class(es) they have. The filters are separated into two categories: city and cost.

- Checking two checkboxes *within* each category should have an additive
  effect (i.e. if I checked 'Hamilton' and 'Toronto' ideally all 
  elements should show up).
- Checking two checkboxes *between* two
  categories should have a subtractive effect (i.e. if I checked
  'Toronto' and 'Cheap Eats', I should only see one blogpost).

The code I have now, currently, works when you have one checkbox checked but doesn't work when you have two checkboxes checked
i.e. if I check 'Toronto' and 'Cheap Eats', both 'Hamilton' and 'Toronto' results come up for 'Cheap Eats'.
i.e. If I select 'Hamilton' and 'Toronto', only 'Hamilton' results come up.

I'm very new to JS and programming in general, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/brsahodL/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#checkboxFilterContainer').find('input:checkbox').on("click", function() {
    var $blogpostsTotal = $('.blogpost').length;
    var $checkboxCategory = $('#checkboxFilterContainer').find('input:checked');
    var $checkboxID = $checkboxCategory.attr('id');

    if ($checkboxCategory.length == 0) {
      $('.blogpost').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
      $('.blogpost').addClass('hide');
      $('.' + $checkboxID).removeClass('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want a bit more?

Comment: @Addis 'hamiltonFilter' and 'torontoFilter' are within the same category ('citiesFilterContainer'); 'splurgeFilter' and 'cheapEatsFilter' are within the same category ('costFilterContainer'). If I click within the same category, I want it to have an OR effect (i.e. show div elements with class 'hamiltonFilter' OR 'torontoFilter'). If I click between categories, I want it to have an AND effect (i.e. show div elements with class 'hamiltonFilter' AND 'cheapEatsFilter'). Does that make more sense?

Comment: The 'AND' part is OK but the 'OR' part doesn't make sense. How do you determine which element to show among the two? You will have to determine which element shows or at least you need some logic to select between the two.

Comment: Just a note, the `for` on your labels should match the `id` of its corresponding checkbox, **not** the `name`. Since all your checkboxes below to the same general group with a shared purpose, they would all probably have the same name (something like "filters"). You can tell whether your labels are properly connected to your inputs or not because if they are you can select the input (check/uncheck a checkbox, select a radio, focus a text input, etc) by clicking the label rather than the input itself. If they're not properly connected, clicking the label will do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `var $checkboxID = $checkboxCategory.attr('id');` will get the first checked element's ID. When multiple checkboxes are selected, you need all the ID's of the checked boxes. In order to do that, you can keep track of them using an array.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#checkboxFilterContainer').find('input:checkbox').on("click", function() {
    var $blogpostsTotal = $('.blogpost').length;
    var $checkboxCategory = $('#checkboxFilterContainer').find('input:checked');
    var $checkboxID = $checkboxCategory.attr('id');
    var $checkboxIDs = [];
    $checkboxCategory.each(function(index, element) {
      $checkboxIDs.push(element.getAttribute('id'));
    });

    if ($checkboxCategory.length == 0) {
      $('.blogpost').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
      $('.blogpost').addClass('hide');
      for (var i = 0; i < $checkboxIDs.length; i++) {
        $('.' + $checkboxIDs[i]).removeClass('hide');
      }

    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this; ( In here `$allClassesAND` works like an `AND` operation. it checks is there any element with all the classes. And the `$allClassesOR` works as `OR` operation. It's trying to match any element which contains one or more matching classes )

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#checkboxFilterContainer').find('input:checkbox').on("click", function() {

    var $blogpostsTotal = $('.blogpost').length;
    var $checkboxCategory = $('#checkboxFilterContainer').find('input:checked');

    if( $checkboxCategory && $checkboxCategory.length !== 0 ) {

      $('.blogpost').addClass('hide');

      let $checkboxID = [];
      for( let index = 0; index < $checkboxCategory.length; index++ ) {
        $checkboxID.push( '.' + $checkboxCategory[index].getAttribute('id') );
      }

      let $allClassesAND = $checkboxID.join('');
      let $allClassesOR = $checkboxID.join(', ');

      if( $( '' + $allClassesAND ).length !== 0 ) {
        $( '' + $allClassesAND ).removeClass('hide');

      } else if( $( '' + $allClassesOR ).length !== 0 ) {
        $( '' + $allClassesOR ).removeClass('hide');

      }


    } else {
      $('.blogpost').removeClass('hide');

    }

  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Already resolved above in several ways, but for deeper reference....

You have correctly set `$checkboxCategory` to contain all of the elements that are currently checked, but the `.attr()` method you are using on the following line (line 6) only grabs the attribute value "for the first element in the set of matched elements."

This is from the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName) regarding that `.attr()` method.

Answer (score 0):

i have shorted and modified it in dynamic way according to your classes.Try this jquery code at your end and here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raghulramkish/0wL9d5ap/)

```
$('.blogpostCategory').change(function () {
 $(".blogpost").hide();
    $('.blogpostCategory:checkbox:checked').each(function () {   
    if($(".blogpost").hasClass( this.id ));
    {  
  $("."+this.id).show();
    }      
  });
 });
```

You can add catagory by defining the className as catagory like below in your html

```
<div class="blogpost hamiltonFilter splurgeFilter" style="display:none;">
  <h3>Toronto Splurge</h3>
</div>
```