# How to narrow search results in a multiple checkbox filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a follow-up to my previous question: [Multiple checkbox filter: how to get both and additive and subtractive effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526659/multiple-checkbox-filter-how-to-get-both-and-additive-and-subtractive-effect)

Many thanks to everyone who helped me in my previous question. Basically, I want to make checkboxes that hide and show div items based on what class(es) they have. The filters are separated into two categories, with two options within each category: **citiesFilter** (hamiltonFilter + torontoFilter) and **costFilter** (cheapEatsFilter + costFilter).

- Checking two boxes *within* each category should increase the number of `<div>` elements that appear (i.e. clicking 'hamiltonFilter' and 'torontoFilter' should show `<div>` elements that have either class)
- Checking two boxes *between* two categories should narrow the number of `<div>` elements that appear (i.e. clicking 'hamiltonFilter' and 'cheapEatsFilter' should ONLY show `<div>` elements that have BOTH classes)

The previous answers work, but only *within* each category; it doesn't narrow the results when I click 'hamiltonFilter' and 'cheapEatsFilter', rather it shows me all `<div>` elements with either class. I tried modifying their code but cannot figure out how to select for `<div>` elements with both classes.

https://jsfiddle.net/de1zc7vx/1/

edit: put in the wrong jfiddle

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#checkboxFilterContainer').find('input:checkbox').on("change", function() {

    var $citiesIDs, $costIDs = [];

    var $citiesCategory = $('#citiesFilterContainer').find('input:checked');
    var $costCategory = $('#costFilterContainer').find('input:checked');

    $citiesCategory.each(function(index, element) {
        $citiesIDs.push(element.getAttribute('id'));
      });

    $costCategory.each(function(index, element) {
        $costIDs.push(element.getAttribute('id'));
      });

    var $totalLength = ($citiesIDs.length + $costIDs.length);

    if ($totalLength == 0) {
       $('.blogpost').removeClass('hide');
      } else {
       $('.blogpost').addClass('hide'); 
       for(i = 0; i < $totalLength; i++) {
           var x = $citiesIDs[i];
           var y = $costIDs[i];
           var xClass = $('.' + x);
           var yClass = $('.' + y);
           $('.x.y').removeClass('hide');     
       }
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the hide class to all the posts
2. Make an OR selector for the selected cities (.firstId,.secondId,...)
3. Make an OR selector for the selected costs
4. If city ids were given, filter the posts by that OR selector
5. If cost ids were given, filter further (or for the first time) by that OR selector
6. For all the posts remaining, remove the hide class

```js
var $filteredPosts = $('.blogpost').addClass('hide');

if ($totalLength) {
  var citiesOrSelector = '.'+ $citiesIDs.join(',.');
  var costsOrSelector = '.'+ $costIDs.join(',.');
  
  if ($citiesIDs.length) $filteredPosts = $filteredPosts.filter(citiesOrSelector);

  if ($costIDs.length) $filteredPosts = $filteredPosts.filter(costsOrSelector);
}
  
$filteredPosts.removeClass('hide');
```